# Kotlin, Fragments, not working, but no errors

Tags: xml, kotlin, fragment

Im currently an intern at Spin Robotics in Denmark.
And therefor ive also been thrown in to unfamiliar grounds in terms of skills.

I was working with getting to knowing Kotlin the first week. like just the basic, making app with datepicker etc.

So basicly i think i have set up it, when i click one the buttons, it should just show me a message for now, ( i wont do the UI until the fragment works)

what am i missing?
i tried several tutorials.
( OBS* the "tool action is here" is not even showing while running. which is supposed to be the "default view/fragment")

MainActivity.kt Code base:

I tried Tutorials, and searching around the internet

```
package com.example.mycbunapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.Window
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.mycbunapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.kassowrobots.api.lang.Load

//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpzuEN8UhUQ
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)



        binding.btnToolAction.setOnClickListener{
            replaceFragment(ToolActionFragment()) // hvis de klikker på den knap ser de den her
        }

        binding.btnLoadScrew.setOnClickListener{
            replaceFragment(LoadScrewFragment()) // hvis de klikker på den knap ser de den her
        }
        binding.btnAttachBit.setOnClickListener{
            replaceFragment(BitAttachFragment()) // hvis de klikker på den knap ser de den her
        }

       // val btnActionTools : Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_toolAction)
       // val btnloadScrew : Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_loadScrew)
       // val btnbitAttach : Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_attachBit)






    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment : Fragment) {
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()

    }

    private fun setFullscreen() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)

    }

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9De9e.png)
```

Comment: Can you add also your fragments' code ?

Comment: fragment XML or the kt

Comment: Both if you can!

Comment: Did you try also clean / rebuild the project ?

Comment: i Got it to work, it was because my mainActivity was a Framedlayout, but the fragments was linear. it is apperantly not allowed for children/Fragments to be any other base than what the base/parent is.